# Ubuntu server 18.04 offline install possible?

Tags: server, 18.04, offline

Is there a way to install Ubuntu server 18.04 without network?
Looks like Ubuntu live server 18-04 does not install without network; if I select a network connection and then disconnect it before install starts, it errors out when it tries to download the current kernel;
apparently Ubuntu server 18.04 refuses to install if it can't download the current kernel and grub/efi from the network;
I didn't see any checkbox for offline install.
On the positive side, it correctly partitions a new disk and installs the efi partition correctly and it is actually bootable;

Comment: Try the [alternative installer](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/?_ga=2.197101739.640645856.1529243436-1242362650.1246318765) (the old way). The [test case](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/389/builds/171113/testcases/1441/results), uses that method.

Comment: @DougSmythies installing using this ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso image worked; the problem was that I previously tried the ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso image which requires net during install to get a kernel and grub; if you mention this as an answer I will accept it